# Is it possible to combine functions for different selectors like this in jquery?

Tags: jquery

Just another silly thought for jquery. Is it possible to do something like this in Jquery:

Instead of typing all three like this:

```
$('#id1').click(function(){
$('#idanother1').animate({height:'100px'},450);
$('#id1').toggleClass('my-added-class');
});

$('#id2').click(function(){
$('#idanother2').animate({height:'100px'},450);
$('#id2').toggleClass('my-added-class');
});

$('#id3').click(function(){
$('#idanother3').animate({height:'100px'},450);
$('#id3').toggleClass('my-added-class');
});
```

I would like to be able to write it something like this:

```
$('#id1' / '#id2' / '#id3').click(function(){
$('#anotherid1' / '#anotherid2' / '#anotherid3').animate({height:'100px'},450);
$('#id1' / '#id2' / '#id3').toggleClass('my-added-class');
});
```

And if I don’t want to add class to id2 I simply exclude it like this:

```
$('#id1' / '' / '#id3').toggleClass('my-added-class');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a mapping between `idx` and `anotheridx` and then you could use the [*multiple selector*](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/). Example:

```
var map  = {
    'id1': $('#anotherid1'),
    'id2': $('#anotherid2'),
    'id3': $('#anotherid3')
};

$('#id1, #id2, #id3').click(function(){
    map[this.id].animate({height:'100px'},450);
    $(this).toggleClass('my-added-class');
});
```

That said, if you have more elements, you should give them a class, so that you can select all elements just by the class name.

It would also be better if you could figure out another *relation* between the elements `idx` and `anotheridx` to not have to maintain an explicit mapping.

But if you need differently functionalities in the click handler, depending on which element was clicked, you have to use separate event handlers. You can, however, identify the comment functionality and put it into its own function and call this one from the handlers:

```
function commenHandler() {
    map[this.id].animate({height:'100px'},450);
    // potentially more code...
}

$('#id1, #id3').click(function(e){
    commenHandler.call(this, e);
    $(this).toggleClass('my-added-class');
});

$('#id2').click(commenHandler);
```

Comment: Example 1 works for me in FF, C and S. But not in IE 7? Any idea why?

Comment: @Hakan: Oh yes, the last comma `'id3': $('#anotherid3'),` breaks the code in IE. Updated it.

Comment: I always forget to check the commas. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the right selectors syntax:

```
$('#id1 , #id2 , #id3').click(function(){...
```

See the JQuery [selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) docs.

Answer (score 0):

If you're relying entirely on the apparent convention of IDs linked by their ending numbers, you can try something like this:

```
var targets = [
  '#id1',
  '#id2',
  '#id3'
];

$(targets.join(',')).click(function(){
  var relatedid = this.id.replace(/(.*\D)(\d+)/i,'$2');
  $('#idanother' + relatedid).animate({height:'100px'},450);
  $(this).toggleClass('my-added-class');
});
```