# How to condense over 150 jquery functions that do the same thing to different divs?

Tags: jquery

im new to jquery and javascript.. Here is the code, this is a sample, on the real page there will be over 150 kinds of drinks, 5 are shown below, is there a way to condense this code? It makes it so when clicking one div another div will bounce. The divs that bounce contain small images, this is used as a giant menu system for finding drinks. thank you for your time and help.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#Pepsi").click(function (){
     $("#Pepsi-Div").delay(600).effect("bounce", { times:3, distance:30 }, 300);
 });
 $("#Coke").click(function (){
     $("#Coke-Div").delay(600).effect("bounce", { times:3, distance:30 }, 300);
 });
 $("#Crush").click(function (){
     $("#Crush-Div").delay(600).effect("bounce", { times:3, distance:30 }, 300);
 });
 $("#7up").click(function (){
     $("#7up-Div").delay(600).effect("bounce", { times:3, distance:30 }, 300);
 });
 $("#RootBeer").click(function (){
     $("#RootBeer-Div").delay(600).effect("bounce", { times:3, distance:30 }, 300);
 });
});
```

Comment: paste the html for these 5 also

Comment: it may help   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081664/is-it-possible-to-combine-functions-for-different-selectors-like-this-in-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on JK's answer, you could try this:

```
$(".drink").click(function (){
    $('#'+$(this).attr('id')+'-Div"]').delay(600).effect("bounce", { times:3, distance:30 }, 300);
 });
```

This selects the element with id `X-Div`, where `X` is the id of the clicked element.

Comment: I suggest `this.id` instead of `$(this).attr('id')` - more efficient at runtime and to type, and in my opinion somewhat easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

Add the same class to every one of those divs (or select based on something that all of those divs have in common:

```
<div id="Coke" class="drink">Coke</div>
<div id="Sprite" class="drink">Sprite</div>
// all divs have the same class="drink"

$(".drink").click(function (){
     $(this).delay(600).effect("bounce", { times:3, distance:30 }, 300);
 });
```

Edit: Update to run the bounce effect on the related div, not the clicked div:

```
$(".drink").click(function (){
     $(this + "-Div").delay(600).effect("bounce", { times:3, distance:30 }, 300);
 });
```

Comment: But `$(this)` wont help. look at the code above. there are two different divs clicked and effected. i mean if `$("#Crush")` is clicked effected is `$("#Crush-Div")` for example.

Comment: Sorry if it wasnt clear, yes there are 2 divs for each drink, the div that is clicked and the div that is effected.

Comment: `$("#" + this.id + "-Div").delay(...)` would do it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your HTML, but it appears you have some elements that each animate another element when clicked.

How about structuring your HTML like this:

```
<div data-bounce-target="#Pepsi-Div">Pepsi</div>
<div data-bounce-target="#Code-Div">Coke</div>
<div data-bounce-target="#7up-Div">7up</div>
<div data-bounce-target="#Crush-Div">Crush</div>
<div data-bounce-target="#Rootbeer-Div">Rootbeer</div>

<div id="Pepsi-Div">I'm a bouncing Pepsi</div>
<div id="Coke-Div">I'm a bouncing Coke</div>
<div id="7up-Div">I'm a bouncing 7up</div>
<div id="Crush-Div">I'm a bouncing Crush</div>
<div id="Rootbeer-Div">I'm a bouncing Rootbeer</div>
```

And then you can generalise your Javascript like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('div[data-bounce-target]').on('click', function () {
        var targetElementId = $(this).data('bounce-target');
        $(targetElementId).delay(600).effect("bounce", { times:3, distance:30 }, 300);
    });
});
```

This way the target element is specified in your HTML code. If you ever need to change the target of an element, you won't have to modify your Javascript. Likewise, when you need to add other elements with a target that needs to bounce, you won't need to change your Javascript.

Here is a [working example in jsFidle](http://jsfiddle.net/fD2zh/).

Answer (score -1):

```
<div id="test" class="divi">test Clicked</div>
<div id="test-Div">test Effected</div>

<div id="test2" class="divi">test2 Clicked</div>
<div id="test2-Div">test2 Effected</div>

<div id="test3" class="divi">test3 Clicked</div>
<div id="test3-Div">tetst3 Effected</div>

<div id="test4" class="divi">test4 Clicked</div>
<div id="test4-Div">test4 Effected</div>

<script>

$(".divi").click(function(){

var var1 = "#" + this.id + "-Div";

$(var1).hide();

});

</script>
```

you can use this however you want. It works with hide() so you can edit it. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/25x9H/2/).